# Xubuntu not bootable from a Legacy BIOS computer?

Tags: boot, xubuntu, uefi, bios

I have an old computer, 2008-ish, which I'm trying to install the new Xubuntu 18.04 on, I used [Etcher](https://etcher.io/) to make a bootable USB. The problem is it doesn't boot from my old computer, meaning when I chose USB in booting options nothing happens and it just boots up my current OS. I tried it on a new laptop with UEFI and it worked. What could be the problem here?

Comment: Maybe you can try this trick https://askubuntu.com/a/1266315/1114033 it solved my problem on legacy BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned the system is older, it may just not be USB boot compatible. That is not uncommon on older systems. If you could list the system specs we could have more information to find a proper answer, or try a search for it.

(EDIT: removed previous solution as it does not apply to OPs system setup)

Gigabyte MBs are notorious for having USB Boot issues. You might be able to get it to boot using HDD+. Try these steps:

1. During BOOT, press DEL and go to your BIOS settings.
2. Make sure that you have both "USB Legacy" and "USB Storage" in the Integrated Peripherals menu.
3. Now, set your Boot Order to HD first, then CD/DVD.
4. Next, plug in your Ubuntu USB and reboot the system.
5. On BOOT, press F12 to pull up the boot menu. Choose HDD+ option.

You should then see your USB device on the next screen. Select it and press ENTER.

Hope this works...

Comment: The motherboard is a GIGABYTE G31M-ES2L with a Core 2 Duo and 4 GBs RAM. It is USB boot compatible because I have installed OSs many times using USBs, but this one doesn't do it for some reason. Unfortunately I'm currently using Xubuntu 17.10 so I can't go for the Windows options. And still I'm curious to know why it's now working, any pointers I can research on?

Comment: Hopefully the new Answer work for you. If it doesn't you could see about updating the firmware on the motherboard. But, there are definitely weird issues with Gigabyte USB boot.

Comment: Thank you. I tried what you mentioned but it didn't work. What I remembered while I was doing the steps though is what solved the problem a long time ago: setting the Hard Disk Booting Priority to the USB before the HDD, and voilà.

Comment: Oh doh! Glad that worked. I assumed you had already tried that one. Nice work!

Comment: I got this on my Gigabyte P35-DS4 but it then stops after turning purple and showing this keyboard symbol in the bottom middle.